# Why doesn't TransactionScope assume success?

Tags: .net, transactionscope

The TransactionScope expects a call to its Complete method as follows. Otherwise the transaction will not be committed.

```
using(TransactionScope scope = new TransactionScope())
{
    /* Perform transactional work here */

    scope.Complete();
}
```

Wouldn't an implementation that assumes success have been more appropriate? This would mean that less code would be required in the standard case (success).

In the case of an exception or a call to a method such as 'Rollback' (this method does not currently exist) the transaction could be rolled back.

```
using(TransactionScope scope = new TransactionScope())
{
    /* Perform transactional work here */

     if(problemOccurred)
     {
         scope.Rollback();
     }
}
```

Note that the problemOccurred flag would only be required in cases where the problem did not result in an exception. In this case, the rollback would be performed automatically.

I am interested in gaining further insight into why this implementation was used.

**Update:** A couple of the answers so far argued that a try-catch block would be required if the implementation that I described were used. This is not the case. The transaction is automatically rolled back when an exception is not handled within the using block. This is the case in both the existing implementation and the one that I described. See 'Completing a transaction scope' section [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms172152.aspx) for further details.

**Update 2:** I finally understand what was being explained in the answers. This is not a language construct that could have been interpreted any way that the language designers saw fit - it is an implementation of the IDisposable pattern. Without the call to Complete the code within the Dispose method would have no knowledge of whether it is being called as the result of the code within the using block being executed successfully or because an exception occurred. I was imagining something similar to the following where both transaction and rollback are keywords.

```
transaction
{
    /* Perform transactional work here */

     if(problemOccurred)
     {
         rollback;
     }
}
```

This would of course present problems if transaction options need to be passed to the TransactionScope.

Comment: Why isn't my comment automatically added when I change page, I shouldn't have to click [Add Comment]...

Comment: From update - The *mechanism* by which the transaction is rolled back in the face of exceptions is that you reach the end of the using block without calling Commit. I.e. that behaviour depends on the exact feature you want to remove.

Comment: Your "update" refers to the current state of play - if TransactionScope assumed success, you'd be changing that situation.

Comment: Your update is wrong - the only reason it currently rolls back is *exactly* the behavior you are complaining about. It assumes failure - if an exception occurs, Complete() is never called and thus the transaction fails. There is no other magic mechanism at work catching the exceptions.

Comment: Sorry guys. I might be missing something here but why can't the transaction always be committed unless a call to (the currently nonexistent) Rollback method is made? I will update the question to include an example of what I am talking about.

Comment: @Scott - try implementing this yourself - all you have to do is implement a class that implements IDisposable, and inside the Dispose method, you have to determine whether you're being disposed as a result of an exception being propagated - and you'll realise why it won't work.

Comment: Then, for bonus points, change the Dispose method again so that if the transaction *should* be committed, but the code covered by the transaction needs to throw an exception out to calling code, then in that case, a commit still occurs

Comment: Thanks Damien. I was thinking of TransactionScope as a language construct that could have been interpreted in any way that the language designers decided but it is nothing more than an implementation of IDisposable.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It means that you don't need to put a manual try/finally (or catch) block (possibly with a "success" flag) in for the failure case. Try rewriting the above code to roll back on error, and look at how much messier it is...

Basically the normal desired behaviour is to only commit if it reaches the end of the block with no exceptions. The simplest way of achieving that is to put a method call to signify success at the end of the block.

Comment: I don't think that a try block is required - see my comment in answer...

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1999461/why-doesnt-transactionscope-assume-success/1999475#1999475

Do you agree?

Comment: No, because you're proposing *changing* that behaviour. *Currently* you don't need a try/catch block precisely because of the behaviour you're complaining about - failure is assumed unless you explicitly commit.

Answer (score 15):

This way, every transaction would look like this:

```
using(TransactionScope scope = new TransactionScope())
{
  try
  {
    /* Perform transactional work here */
  }
  catch (Exception)
  {
    scope.Rollback();
    throw;
  }
}
```

Which is more code.

**Edit:**

Everything else is risky or bad style. **You have to be absolutely sure that there wasn't any error when committing**. When leaving the using block, you don't know if you leave it because an exception is thrown or because you just reached the end of it. When calling `Complete`, you know.

The transaction block syntax is already the **simplest you can do**. Just implement the transaction without any special error handling and commit it at the end. You don't have to care and rolling back when any error occurs. Consider, exceptions can be thrown in almost every single line of code (eg. NullReference, Overflows, InvalidOperation etc). So what could be easier than this?

Comment: If you use the scope.Complete() approach, when would a rollback occur if it was warranted?

Comment: An exception within the TransactionScope's using block would automatically roll back the transaction. Here an except from MSDN.

"Failing to call this method aborts the transaction, because the transaction manager interprets this as a system failure, or equivalent to an exception thrown within the scope of transaction."

Your try block is redundant.

Comment: Here is the link for the except.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms172152.aspx

Comment: This answer was a hypothetical illustration of an auto-`Complete()`ing `TransactionScope`. The Microsoft comment applies only to a non-auto-`Complete()`ing version, the current version.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I am picturing a bit of a hybrid then - one in which the transaction is auto committed except in the case of an exception.

Comment: @Scott - that would require changes inside the CLR to achieve - You'd need some magical new way of intercepting unhandled exceptions

Answer (score 4):

If the other implementation had been chosen, then people would be asking the converse question!

Seriously though, the default behaviour in a mechanism designed to protect against partial or incorrect updates surely has to be **not** to commit, doesn't it?

Answer (score 3):

I think the amount of code to write for success is, as @Jon Skeet says, less (and less ugly) the current way.  From a transaction point of view, however, I would think that you would **want** to be pessimistic and assume that unless success was explicitly indicated you would roll it back.  Committing a transaction in error is a much worse problem, in my opinion, than accidentally failing to commit a successful transaction because of a code error.